# how to reference an instance created in another class

Tags: java

I have a function in Class A which I would like to change the value of a field in Class B.

Class C has my `main()` and creates a new instance of class B and Class A. Class A is from an API and one of their functions is a listener function. I would like for that listener function to be able to change the field of Class B, but when I write the code for the listener function, it doesn't recognize Class B's instance.

How do I reference that instance?

Example code:

```
public class A {
     public void listenermethod(){
            //can't reference Binstance <-------
     }
}

public class B {
     B.field = 1;
}

public class C {
     A Ainstance = new A();
     B Binstance = new B(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give A class a private B field, and then you can call the public methods from B on this field as needed. If you need to create both A and B instances in a separate class (C) you should give your A class a `public void setB(B b)` setter method.

A.java

```
class A {
  private B b;

  public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

  public void listenerMethod() {
    if (b != null) {
      b.someBMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

C.java

```
public class C {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    a.setB(b);

    a.listenerMethod();

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a reference to the instance b.

Comment: @Tanner is `if (b != null)` even necessary considering he sets it in class C?

Comment: @Chowza It is good practice as you are never sure that `b` is not null.

Comment: @Chowza: if you pass B in via A's constructor and make sure that A has no default constructors, ones that don't pass in a B instance, then the null check may not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be able to modify both class C and class A. Rewrite the class A method to

```
public void listenermethod(Binstance theB){
            theB.something = "some_value";
     }
```

Now when you call class A, pass in the Binstance. If you can't modify class A, then your task can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

An instance by definition belongs to an object.  Therefore, your class A must either have an object of class B as a member:

```
Class A{

     private B instance_of_b;

}
```

now you can access B members like this:

```
instance_of_b.member
```

or the field belonging to class B could be static and then A could access it through the class.

```
B.member
```

Also make sure you know the meaning of accessor keywords (private,protected,[friendly],public).